# How to correctly pass args to ggplot stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried to fix this problem a number of ways, but I am new to R, so I don't know the tips and tricks. I am trying to graph a polynomial function using code for a quadratic function, provided by my teacher, however, I keep running into the "unused arguments error". the issue is that I have given three arguments, which is what the function expects. this is the code I entered:

```
> quadratic <- function(x, u.values){
+ X <- cbind(1, x, x^2)
+ return(X %*% u.values)
+ }
> dev.new()
> ggplot() +
+ geom_point(aes(x = t,y = y),data= GData)+
+ stat_function(fun=quadratic(args=c(1.9604816, -0.1201548, -4.9768049)))
Error in quadratic(args = c(1.9604816, -0.1201548, -4.9768049)) : 
  unused argument(s) (args = c(1.9604816, -0.1201548, -4.9768049))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `quadratic` function has two parameters named `x` and `u.values` and you are passing in an argument named `args=` with three values that doesn't match either named parameter.

Answer (score 8):

As you've defined it, `quadratic` doesn't have an `args` parameter. That's what's causing your error.

I'm guessing -- but I can't test, since your example isn't reproducible -- that you should change `args` in your `stat_function` call to something like `args = list(u.values = c(1.9604816, -0.1201548, -4.9768049))`.

Edit:

To clarify, `args` parameter of `stat_function` takes additional arguments to the function you specify (`quadratic` in this case) as a `list`. What you're doing is passing a named argument `args` to `quadratic`, when you want to be passing a named argument `args` to `stat_function`.

Here is a reproducible example that works:

```
g <- data.frame(t = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1), y = seq(2.1, 3, by = 0.1))

quadratic <- function(x, u.values){
    X <- cbind(1, x, x^2)
    return(X %*% u.values)
}

ggplot(data = g, aes(x = t, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    stat_function(fun = quadratic, 
                  args = list(u.values = c(1.9604816, -0.1201548, -4.9768049)))
```

[image]

Obviously this data has nothing to do with yours, but the `quadratic` function is applied correctly to the data and the results are plotted.

Comment: Thankyou very much. :) I didn't think that I might need to define the args function too.. but it makes sense....